# Accessing XML declarations with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have a file which has the following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ODX MODEL-VERSION="2.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="odx.xsd">
  <?Some_XML_Declarations 1?>
  <?DocumentSaveNo 0?>
  <other-elements/>
</ODX>
```

Currently I'm using lxml and objectify, is there any way of accessing these XML declarations (e.g. `DocumentSaveNo`)?

I have scoured the lxml API page but found nothing.

Comment: hmm, by doing a `dir`, one can see that they exist: `['DocumentSaveNo', 'Some_XML_Declarations', ...redacted..., 'other-elements', ...]`, but trying to access them results in an error: `AttributeError: no such child: DocumentSaveNo`. It's possible using lxml's etree, if not with lxml's objectify.

Comment: Is that exactly what your xml looks like?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, it is much bigger but the basics is the same. The XML declaration, then the opening tag then some more declarations followed by a single `<other-elements/>` which can contain other tags.